# How to set the rotation point and use Transform Each in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, tools, transform, illustrator-scripting

I have a triangle I'm trying to rotate in Illustrator using the `Object->Transform->Transform Each` command, but I can't figure out how to set the rotation point like I can if I just use `Free Transform`.

This is important because the rotation point is at the center of the square bounding box, not at the center of the triangle.

Is there a way to set the rotation point? Or do I have to manipulate the bounding box somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is a way to permanently alter an object's rotate point.  You can use the Rotate tool or Free Transform to change it temporarily, but it resets to the center of the object once you change to a different tool.

If you just do a simple rotate using the selection tool instead of Rotate or Transform Each, it will use the bounding box.  Otherwise you're stuck with the object's calculated center.

Comment: Yeah, bummer. I really wanted to find a way with the Transform Each tool because I would be CTRL+D-ing the transformation to repeat it multiple times. Would take more time to do a rotate, then a resize each time, etc.

Comment: Actually [T11's method](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/5570/3327) works well, and can be used to effectively permanently alter the centre used in Transform Each scaling, moving or rotation. The slight variant in my comment on that answer is good for temporarily changing the centre.

Answer (score 36):

There  is a way with the *Rotate Tool* (<kbd>R</kbd>)

1. Select your triangle
2. Click the Rotate tool
3. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> click where you want your center to be.
4. A dialog should popup prompting for an angle. You can go on an fill it out.

When ready press the "Copy" Button and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for `transform again` as many times as you want copies.

Edit:
After understanding that the object should be BOTH rotated and moved- or scaled- each.
What about adding "hidden" (no line no fill) artwork to transform the bounding box so the center is where you want it to? You could then `transform each` this group any way you like.

If you don't like the hidden artwork you could make your object with the hidden objects a symbol. Then you could transform/rotate/scale it and in the end edit the symbol. This way all instances get updated accordingly. This might, however change the position of each of these instances.

Comment: Clever...... +1

Comment: Yeah, I knew about ALT+Clicking for the rotate tool, but unfortunately it looks impossible to move the rotation point for a Transform Each.

Comment: @bccarlso I got it wrong then. You want to rotate AND move/scale each...

Answer (score 9):

I realize I'm a bit late to this, but in case anyone else is wondering, there is a workaround that may be helpful. I can create a one-point object (just click with the pen tool, for example) and group it with the object that I want to be able to control the rotation center on. The new **group** now has a center between the original object and the "one-point" object, so I have plenty of control over where that is. I'm just manipulating the group instead of the object.

Note that instead of making an object that has just one point, you can also create a regular shape and just make it invisible.

Comment: I was just about to post saying more or less the same. I call it "green screening" because I use bright green rectangles at low opacity, grouped behind each object - then when I'm done `transform-each`ing, I select one green rectangle with the direct selection tool (`A`), then `select > same > fill color` and delete them all. Makes cleanup easy and means there's no need to ungroup after and risk accidentally ungrouping too far.

Answer (score 5):

erm.. the bounding box center is the same as the object's center. The two points are always identical. The Bounding Box is drawn form the objects center to its outermost edges.

You can somewhat adjust the rotation point by using the 9 point origin box in the Transform Each options dialog.

[image: Transform each]

But if you are looking for free form placement of the origin point, you won't get that with any automated rotation. You'd need to look at scripting.

Answer (score 4):

You could script this. The center of a triangle is the barycentric coordinate, which is just the vector average. So:

```
#target illustrator
// CC BY SA Janne Ojala 2014

function rotate_around_vertex_average(obj, ang) {
    var points = obj.pathPoints;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    for(var i=0; i < points.length; i++){
        point = points[i];
        x += point.anchor[0];
        y += point.anchor[1];
    }
    var x_c = x/points.length;
    var y_c = y/points.length;

    var rot = getRotationMatrix(15);
    var mov = getTranslationMatrix(x_c, y_c);
    var inv = invertMatrix(mov);
    var mtx = concatenateMatrix(inv, rot);
    var mtx = concatenateMatrix(mtx, mov);
    obj.transform(mtx, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, Transformation.DOCUMENTORIGIN);
}

objs = app.selection;
for(var i in objs){
    obj = objs[i];
    rotate_around_vertex_average(obj, 15);
}
```

Comment: errr.. sorry.. I read it :)

Comment: @Scott cool then i will make more answers

Answer (score 2):

The way I do this is:

1. Convert first the object to symbol.
2. Center the object where you want, if you want align the symbol with your reference object, it mean the pivots are coincident now.
3. Double click in the symbol to enter in edit mode.
4. Change the position of your symbol where you want.
5. Exit edit mode and you should have the pivot of your symbol out of the symbol and placed exactly where you need.

Comment: Seems as if the pivot point placement in Symbol Edit Mode don't work with Transform Each... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I would explore the actions panel - you could create a new action that rotates, then scales, for example. Then apply that action to the object/s you wish to have rotated and scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this site out](https://web.archive.org/web/20170815211100/http://www.avenza.com:80/resources/blog/2011/02/23/defining-symbol-registration-point-adobe-illustrator-cs5). It will give you a way:

> When the graphic is dragged into the Symbols panel, the Symbols
>   Options dialog box appears. In it, you can type a name for the new
>   symbol.
>
> An easy way of setting the registration point is to click one of the
>   positions available on the registration option matrix. The default
>   registration point is set to the centre of the matrix. In total, there
>   are nine registration point positions to choose from. After a graphic
>   is registered as a symbol, the registration point is indicated by a
>   black crosshair when the symbol is selected.
>
> In order to tweak the registration point position, double-click a
>   symbol to enter isolation mode. In isolation mode, the registration
>   point is stationary, meaning that to change the position of it, the
>   symbol should be moved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your object & select rotate tool
2. Move the pivot to your desired position
3. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Drag</kbd> to rotate
4. <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate

Note: Dont change the tool.  Just rotate.

Answer (score 0):

In Illustrator CC 2014:

1. Select object
2. Press the **R** key
3. Move reference point

( Use the Rotate Tool not the Object>Transform>Rotate or Free Transform )

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rotating-reflecting-objects.html#rotate_objects

Answer (score 0):

Make a circle with it's centre wherever you need your pivot (use snapping if useful) that is larger than the extent of the object or objects you intend to rotate. Send to Back ( shift+ctrl+[ ) so it is behind your objects, just so you can see them easily.  then select the object or objects you want to rotate plus your new circle, and rotate away.  Delete when you're done or, if you want this new pivot to be permanent, make the fill and outline of the circle null and group it with the object or objects.

Comment: Hi Howard, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the help center or ping one of us in the Graphic Design Chat once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd chime in here for a really simple solution:

So I was needing the reference point to be changed to the top middle, and found that it's really easy to do in the Transform panel. There's a diagram on the left with 9 small boxes arranged in a square. By selecting the top middle point, I can punch in parameters into the Transform panel and it'll make the changes I need. I was using it for an action for centering the top of art on a tshirt mockup and it worked like a charm. Works the same for typing in the amount of rotation you need. And then, when you're done, you can select the middle point again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. Adobe really needs to make this easier like the rotation works in Flash aka Animate. I had a few elements I needed to rotate from a center point. They could not be grouped together as I wanted to rotate them interdependently and set a custom center point.

1. Before you do anything, select the vector shapes you want to rotate copying them into another layer and making them another color so you can easily see them. Lock this layer.
2. Now in my case I had 2 elements I wanted to rotate. Select each one dragging it into the Symbols panel and name them. Do this for all of your shapes individually.
3. Double click the symbol on your art-board to edit the symbol definition and you will see it in an onion skin-like view. Position it so the black cross hair is where you want your custom center point to be.
4. Now exit out of this mode by clicking the back arrow and nudge the artwork so it's in the position your copy is.
5. Delete the copy layer.

Adobe needs to make it so that you can easily use the rotate tool and permanently change the center point of vector artwork so that when you deselect something it does not reset it to the center.

Answer (score -1):

EASY SOLUTION

1. Center your triangle on an axis point. Then create a square or circle with a different color stroke that is larger than the triangle but also centered on the same axis. (This will center both shapes where you want them. More importantly it puts the axis point on the center of the triangle.)
2. Then select both objects.
3. Then Choose: Object > Transform > Transform Each > Rotate, Scale, Shift, Reflect, or do whatever you want to do.
4. Click copy to have the effects take place on that axis point.
5. Then Duplicate as many times as needed by hitting (command D)
6. Select one object with the different colored stroke.
7. Then go to: Select > Same > Stroke Color > HIT DELETE.

VOILA!

This rotates your triangle from the center point how you wanted it to move and gets rid of all the other unneeded shapes.

Answer (score -1):

Use rotate tool or press R, then hold shift until X and Y coordinate show, after that click your center rotation.
Try to rotate your object :)

Comment: The OP already mentions that this is possible with regulation transformations. What they're trying to do is replicate this ability when using Transform Each (simultaneously transforming multiple objects in a selection in the same way without treating them as a group).