# How to rotate a shape around a custom center point using the transformation effect in the appearance panel in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, appearance, rotate

How to rotate a shape around a custom center point using the appearance panel **transform effect** in Illustrator.

let's say I have a shape I want to rotate it incrementally around a specific center outside the **reference point locator** , and that center point is anywhere in the artboard. But with the **transform effect** in the appearance panel.

What I did and fail is a **Move** transformation over the shape and rotate the result with another added transformation, but I got nothing. I got the same result as if I rotate it without moving it from its original place.

[image]

What I need is to determine a center outside the shape I want to rotate and incrementally rotate it using the appearance **transform effect** in Illustrator. like the hereunder screenshot:

[image]

To be more clearer

My question focus on using transformation effect in the ((appearance)) panel ... not the rugualr rotation command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the rotation point and use Transform Each in Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1668/how-to-set-the-rotation-point-and-use-transform-each-in-illustrator)

Comment: no, my question focus on using ((appearance)) panel ... not the rugualr rotation command

Comment: Theres no way to do this directly. The only workaround is to do what Vincent said and use an invisible object, but that will affect all instances so you can't have a different offset for each effect on a single object

Comment: @hsawires I see that. but if you read the answers you'll find that there is no way to permanently alter an object's rotate point to a custom point outside of the object. Meaning you won't be able to do it with the appearance panel either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sneaky workaround would be to add a single point, no stroke, no fill, that is located at the desired center of rotation. Group the two objects, and apply the effect to the group. Choose the reference point wisely and you will have your effect.