# How to align an object to inside of circle stroke in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, alignment

First of all, I am very new to illustrator. I have a circle with stroke only (Fill color is turned off). An angular object was created using two straight lines as in the following picture.

I have to align that angular object- "1" to inside of circle stroke so that it aligns as angular object- "2".

[image]

How can I do it precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to outline mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) and then manually align one of them until it looks good (make sure to zoom in).

<sub>▲ It will help to turn off all automatic snapping for this part</sub>

[image: lined up]

Now use the *Rotate Tool* (<kbd>R</kbd>) and with *Smart Guides* on (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to toggle on/off) click in the center of the circle to rotate *around* that point (your Smart Guides will snap to the center once you get close).

[image: Center snapping]

**Follow the steps from [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/1670/63979) for rotating.**

In the rotate dialog enter in the value `360/c` (or 45° in your case)

<sup>**c** = amount of copies you want to have around your circle.</sup>

Press **Copy**

Now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> a few times to fill it up

[image: rotation and repeat process]

---

**▼ Skip below mentioned and just follow steps from [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/1670/63979) for rotating.**

*Saved for historical significance of my backwards approach to this:*

Now while holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> (to copy the path) and <kbd>Shift</kbd> (to snap) you can *Click+Drag* the shape around your circle until 180° <sup><sub>[See footnote]</sub></sup>

Select both and while the *Rotate Tool* is still active, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[Old GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERZHL.gif)

<sub>I thought you could simply place the pointer where you want to rotate around and then use something like *Transform Effects* to rotate and place all the copies - or even the regular rotation panel, but when I tried that it reset my *rotate-around-point*.</sub>
<sub>Therefore, you first have to make a copy 180°, *that* will set the center point where you want it.</sub>
<sub>**[Edit: there is a way](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/1670/63979)**</sub>

Comment: Hi WELZ, Thanks for your elaborative answer. However I know how to rotate along a path or circle using Transform tool. What I was confused about how to place the arrow (angular object) on the stroke so that it will not displace while rotating. Thanks again for your cordial Help!

Comment: Just trying to help, my pleasure! I guess outline mode is all you needed (it's a great thing to have sometimes).