# How to increase marker size in Illustrator Scatter Graph?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, data-visualisation, chart-design, graph

I'm very new to using Illustrator and have been trying to make some scientific graphs.  I have a scatter graph here that looks alright, but the markers on the graph are just too small!  To get the different markers, I made the shapes and then converted them into a design, then changed the bland square markers into that design.  But they're frankly too tiny, and I need them bigger.  Is there any way to increase the marker size?  My first idea was to just scale the markers, but when you scale an object, it doesn't stay centered where it was before.  This is unacceptable for a chart that is supposed to accurate represent my data.  Now I could manually copy all the markers, scale them up, then TRY to overlay them on top of the old markers perfectly, but that sounds really tedious and will result in a lot of small errors in marker placement. But is there any better alternative?

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Test Scatter Graph]

Comment: Why are you not using symbols?

Comment: @joojaa I could not find suitable symbols in the default available libraries, and it's simple enough to make triangles and x's.  All that aside, it seems that the markers in a graph cannot be edited using the Transform Each feature, so I think I have no choice other than to manually put some kind of symbol, shape, etc. on top of each marker myself so that they can be manipulated.  :(

Comment: you do know that once youve drawn a triangle you can designate it as a symbol. Ive never used the default livrary items for anything.

Comment: @joojaa Like I said, the whole issue became irrelevant once I realized that markers in graphs cannot be resized as a group.  So whether it's a symbol or not doesn't really matter in this case.  Thankfully, someone explained to me how to create larger customer markers, so my problem was solved eventually!  :)

Comment: Yeah its a bit interesting design to not let user place pivot on things and force them to use dummy objects to force bb centre. Anyway, do yourself a favor dont use the graph functions of illustrator. Roll your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on the Adobe help forums, and someone gave me an answer that actually worked! Here's what you have to do:

When you create custom markers, they are scaled in reference to the original marker size that Illustrator creates when you make a graph.

> So what you have to do is draw a square, make it invisible (no stroke,
> no fill) and draw your custom design as large as you want it to be
> compared to it. When defining your custom marker, the invisible square
> has to be the bottommost object and you have to select it along with
> the elements that make your custom design.
>
> It's straightforward when you draw the square in the exact same size
> as Illustrator's default marker, but you don't have to.

Here's the response on the forum for reference: https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/how-to-increase-marker-size-in-illustrator-scatter-graph/m-p/12196114#M284815

I just tested it out, and it really works! My new marker designs came out much larger than the default marker size!

P.S. I'm also confirming here that Transform Each does not work on graph markers, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select all the objects you want to enlarge, then do *Object > Transform > Transform each*
2. Type in a percentage for the enlargement in both the horizontal and vertical
3. Make sure the centre reference point is checked to ensure the scaled objects will remain centred
4. Enable the preview to check it, then hit OK

**Note**: if some of your markers consist of strokes, make sure you also check the *Scale Strokes and Effects* option.

[image]

Comment: Triangles will not scale correctly as the center of a triangle and the center of its boundingbox dont coencide. See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91467/why-do-triangles-do-this-with-alignment/91477#91477 and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1668/how-to-set-the-rotation-point-and-use-transform-each-in-illustrator/36653#36653

Comment: @joojaa - yeah I know, but as long as the scaling is not massive, it will only be small difference. The positions of triangles might need to be adjusted afterwards manually if absolute accuracy is required.

Comment: @joojaa - that script you reference certainly looks like a good solution for triangles

Comment: Yeah but they are most likely fonts of somekind. We jyst dont know.

Comment: @joojaa - yup, possibly. Using symbols as you suggested in your comment is probably the best approach, but too late if the artwork is already made.

Comment: For some reason, when I select all the objects I'm using as markers and try hitting "transform each" the dialogue  box does not appear.  I tested it out with other shapes, and it seems to work fine.  I don't know what it is about these shapes (a circle, a triangle, and the letter 'x') but I can't use the transform each tool.  I've tried it with all markers and just markers of one shape.

For reference, I just drew two lines and tested Transform Each on those lines, and it worked fine.  But cannot use it on my graph markers.

Comment: @KumaAra - it might depend on how they were constructed. There's no way to tell unfortunately without access to your file.

Comment: @BillyKerr I tested it with a fresh graph where I just generated some random data and didn't make any changes.  Then I tested the Transform Each on different sets of markers.  As it turns out, you cannot Transform Each with markers in a graph, sadly.  So it was not an issue of my own created markers, but a very unfortunate feature of graph markers in general.  :(

Comment: @kumaAra - what do you mean by "graph markers"?  Are these not just shapes you created in Illustrator?

Comment: @BillyKerr Illustrator has many graphing features. When you input data into the graph, it automatically maps out all the data points onto your graph.  The data points are represented by "markers" on the graph (markers is literally just what Illustrator calls them).  You do not make them yourself, they are automatically generated and placed by Illustrator.  To better visualize my data, I replaced the original markers (gray squares) with different colored shapes using Object -> Graph -> Design -> New Design.  This allows you to upload selected graphics as new marker shapes.

Comment: Ah, I see, you mean the Graph tool.  Can't you just ungroup it after you have finished making the graph. Then you should be able to select and manipulate the points. Note this will disable the graph object and its data, so keep a copy if you need to adjust the data later.